# try implement SQLGrammarException into method Java

Tags: java, hibernate

im trying to implement SQLGrammarException into my method.
This method show me column error, but i need to show what procedure the column with error from.

```
    public static PersistenceMicrodataException dealHibernateException(Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Throwable t = ExceptionUtil.getCause(e);
    return new PersistenceMicrodataException(t.getMessage(), t);
 }
```

I try this:

```
public static PersistenceMicrodataException dealHibernateException(Throwable e) {
    try {
        Throwable t = ExceptionUtil.getCause(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        System.out.println(((SQLGrammarException) t).getSQLState());
        System.out.println(((SQLGrammarException) t).getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(t.getCause());
    }
    return new PersistenceMicrodataException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

```
public static PersistenceMicrodataException dealHibernateException(Throwable e) {
    String concatError = ((SQLGrammarException) e).getSQL() + ((SQLGrammarException) e).getClass() + ((SQLGrammarException) e).getCause();
    while (e != null) {
        java.lang.System.out.println(concatError);
        break;
    }           
    Throwable t = ExceptionUtil.getCause(e);
    return new PersistenceMicrodataException(concatError,t);
}
```